# Pymongo auto sort the input dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, geospatial, pymongo

I am using Pymongo to access Mongo db. I want to search for all people nearby a specified location with name contains a string. For example, I want to search all people nearby [105.0133, 21.3434] and name contains 'Mark'. So I write the query like this:

```
db.users.find({ "location.coords": { "$nearSphere": [105.0133, 21.3434], "$maxDistance": 10/EARTH_RADIUS }, "name": "/Mark/" })
```

(I have an index "location.coords" in my "users" collection)

The query works fine in Mongodb console, but while execute by Pymongo, the dictionary being re-sort like this:

```
{ "name": "/Mark/", "location.coords": { "$nearSphere": [105.0133, 21.3434], "$maxDistance": 10/EARTH_RADIUS } }
```

(The "name" key is before "location.coords", that is not what I expected - also Mongodb expected)

That causes Mongodb cannot understand the query and returns no results. Can anyone help me to figure out how to force the Pymongo does not re-sort my dictionary.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary type is inherently orderless. From the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary).

If you want to index your dictionary in a specific order, you'll have to store your order somehow. One easy way to do this is to keep your keys in a list, like:

```
mongo_keys = ["location.coords", "name"]
for k in mongo_keys:
    do_something(mongo_result[k])
```

You also might want to [investigate](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> class **collections.OrderedDict([items])**
>
> Return an instance of a dict
>   subclass, supporting the usual dict methods. An OrderedDict is a dict
>   that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. If a new entry
>   overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left
>   unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the
>   end.

Unfortunately if you need more help than that, you'll need to provide more details of your situation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please give me a suggestion for OrderedDict object since I am using Python 2.6, the collections.OrderedDict is available in 2.7 only.

Comment: @ofecrpnr: My suggestion is that you don't use an ordered dict then. Just stick with the basics, if you preserve your key order in a list then you'll always have a consistent order to index into your dictionary. Remember, in python you want to keep it simple. Can you explain why you need the ordering? Please add this detail to your original post and maybe I can suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't the ordering, it's `"/Mark/"`. The notation with forward slashes is a convenience provided by the javascript shell, and don't constitute a part of the regular expression pattern itself (unless you meant for them to be literal slashes, in which case I've misunderstood your question).

To use a regular expression ("contains") filter in PyMongo, you need to pass a Python regular expression object. Try this:

```
{ "name": re.compile("Mark"), "location.coords": { "$nearSphere": [105.0133, 21.3434], "$maxDistance": 10/EARTH_RADIUS } }
```